# R shiny: RenderUI of switchInput not displaying

Tags: css, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I am trying to have the following `switchInput` appearance:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #1ee38d;
                                        }'))),
  
  #switchInput color while off
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-warning,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-warning {
                                        background: #00bfff;
                                        }'))),
  switchInput(inputId = "ans_1", value = TRUE,
              onLabel = "T", onStatus = "success", offStatus = "warning", 
              offLabel = "F")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I am unsuccessful in attempting to do so via `renderUI` and `uiOutput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #1ee38d;
                                        }'))),
  
  #switchInput color while off
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-warning,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-warning {
                                        background: #00bfff;
                                        }'))),
  uiOutput("ex1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
   output$ex1 = renderUI({
     switchInput(inputId = "ans_1", value = TRUE,
                 onLabel = "T", onStatus = "success", offStatus = "warning", 
                 offLabel = "F")})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Help appreciated in facilitating it working via renderUI. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify proper widths with `labelWidth` and `handleWidth` args. I set them to 100 pixels each. It seems that auto widths are not adjusted correctly under the `renderUI`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ex1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$ex1 = renderUI({
    tagList(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #1ee38d;
                                        }'))),
      
      #switchInput color while off
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-warning,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-warning {
                                        background: #00bfff;
                                        }'))),
    switchInput(inputId = "ans_1", value = TRUE,
                onLabel = "T", onStatus = "success", offStatus = "warning", 
                offLabel = "F",
                labelWidth = "100",
                handleWidth = "100")
  )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That's helpful, thank you, @polkas. With respect to the colours not rendering as specified in my CSS tag, would you have an idea how to solve? Thanks

Comment: You can include the CSS in a `tagList()` within the `renderUI`. I've shown how in a separate answer as it's too much to type in a comment

Comment: @Baroque your solution unfortunately not works for both problems:)

Comment: @Baroque at least my example is working properly, truly tagList works for CSS.

Comment: Odd, my example works fine when I run it. What problems are you having?

Comment: Thanks, @polkas and @Baroque for your help. @Baroque, your example renders the colours correctly, but I think needs ```labelWidth``` and ```handleWidth``` rather than ```width```.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, using the `width` option set to 200. Also preserves your CSS styling by including in a `tagList`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #1ee38d;
                                        }'))),
    
    #switchInput color while off
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-warning,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-warning {
                                        background: #00bfff;
                                        }'))),
    uiOutput("ex1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    output$ex1 <- renderUI({
        tagList(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #1ee38d;
                                        }'))),
                
                #switchInput color while off
                tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-warning,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-warning {
                                        background: #00bfff;
                                        }'))),
        switchInput(inputId = "ans_1", value = TRUE,
                    onLabel = "T", onStatus = "success", offStatus = "warning", 
                    offLabel = "F", width="200px"))})
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, @polkas and @Baroque. @Baroque, I think you need include ```labelWidth``` and ```handleWidth``` rather than ```width```